# CakePHP different tables displays in the same page

Tags: cakephp, view, model, controller

I'd like to make website, with news and comments attached to them.
I made Model Infos.php ( connected to news on my page) and Model Infos_coms.php ( where comment should be saved for each news). For each Model I've got controlleres as follows

InfosController.php

```
class InfosController extends AppController
{
public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session');
public $components = array('Session');

public function index()
{

    $this->set('inform', $this->Info->find('all'));
    //$this->loadModel('Infos_com');
    //$this->set('com', $this->Infos_com->find('all'));
}}
```

, Info_comsController.php.

```
<?php
class Infos_comsController extends AppController
{
public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session');
public $components = array('Session');

public function index()
{
    $this->set('com',  $this->Infos_com->find('all'));
}}
```

**and there is my problem, couse i don't know how to display both tables (news and their comments on one page)**

here is my index, i've red twice cookbook chapter about view and i didn't find there answer for solving my problem.

here is my Index file in folder (View/Infos)

```
<body>
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Dodaj newsa',true),array('action'=>'add')); ?>
<div class="container">
<?php
foreach ($inform as $news) : ?>

    <h3>
        <?php echo $news['Info']['title']; ?>
    </h3>
    <p>
        <?php echo $news['Info']['body']; ?>
    </p>
    <small>
        <?php echo $news['Info']['created']; ?>
    </small>
    <small>IP: 
        <?php echo $news['Info']['ip']; ?>
    </small>

<!-- existing comments -->

        <?php foreach ($com as $comment): ?>
        <h4>
            <?php echo $comment['Infos_com']['body']; ?>
        </h4>
        <small>
            <?php echo $comment['Infos_com']['created']; ?><br>
            <?php echo $comment['Infos_com']['ip']; ?>
        </small>

        <!-- adding comments -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $this->Form->create('Infos_com'); ?>
            <?php echo $number = $comment['Info']['id']; ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input(__('mail',true),array('class'=>'form-control')) ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input(__('Comment body',true), array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Dodaj komentarz',true),array('class'=>'btn btn-info')); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
        </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php endforeach; unset($news); unset($comment);?>
```

i will be gratefull for any tip

**Edit.**
I followed Guillemo Mansilla suggest, but now i got issue with database. I've used Guillemo Mansilla code, with changed names, and also adde something i think correctly. There are my Modal

Info.php

```
<?php

class Info extends AppModel
{
public $hasMany = array('Infos_com');
public $validate = array(
    'title'=>array(
        'rule'=>'notEmpty'
    ),
    'body'=>array(
        'rule'=>'notEmpty'
    )
);
}
?>
```

Infos_com.php

```
<?php

class Infos_com extends AppModel
{
public $belongsTo = array('Info');
public $validate = array(
    'mail'=>array(
        'requierd'=>array(
            'rule'=>'notEmpty',
            'message'=>'Write your email'
        )
    ),
    'body'=>array(
        'rule'=>'notEmpty',
        'message'=>'Write a comment'
    )
);
}
?>
```

i changed my index.ctp inside body part to

```
<?php if (isset($inform)) {
foreach($inform as $info) {
        echo $info['Info']['title'];
        foreach($info['Infos_com'] as $comment) {
            echo $comment['Infos_com']['body'];
        }
    }
} ?>
```

now i'm getting error

> Database Error
>   Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Infos_com.info_id' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT `Infos_com`.`id`, `Infos_com`.`id_infos`, `Infos_com`.`username`, `Infos_com`.`mail`, `Infos_com`.`ip`, `Infos_com`.`created`, `Infos_com`.`body`, `Infos_com`.`info_id` FROM `blogdb`.`infos_coms` AS `Infos_com` WHERE `Infos_com`.`info_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

i have both tables so i don't understand where is mistake.

Comment: You should follow the naming [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that your associations are correct, that is, Info hasMany Infos_com, so in your Info Model you have something like

```
public $hasMany => array('Infos_com')
```

I am going to assume that both models are correctly created (You didn't paste your models)

Now, in your controller InfosController, just do this

```
$this->Info->recursive = 1;
$this->set('inform', $this->Info->find('all'));
```

In your view, you will have all "infos" along with its comments in a var named $inform, just iterate over it recursively

```
if (isset($inform)) {
    foreach($inform as $info) {
        echo $info['Info']['title']; //I dont even know if you have a field named "title"
        foreach($info['Infos_com'] as $comment) {
            echo $comment['Infos_com']['comment'];
        }
    }
}
```

bear in mind that this piece of code probably don't work because we use different names, just adapt it to what you have in there

Comment: i followed your instructions, even read about it in cookbook, and becouse of You i receive much progess, but i have some issues still, so please take a look of them . Nevertheless, THANK YOU

Comment: sure! I will follow Anil Kumar words here too, try to stick to conventions.

Comment: I solved it, thank You for help :)
answer is down below
(We gave one index too much in index file), also database wanted different column name than i had.

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly make it , after all night !!!

1. i Changed column name in my Infos_com from id_infos to info_id
2. next i edit my index code to

   ```
   <?php if (isset($inform)) {
   foreach($inform as $info) {
       echo $info['Info']['title']; echo '<br>';
       echo $info['Info']['body']; echo '<br>';
       foreach($info['Infos_com'] as $comment) {
           echo $comment['body']; echo '<br>';
           echo $comment['mail']; echo '<br>';
       }
   }
   } ?>
   ```

and finnaly i got my comment under my news, THANK YOU !